# Nim Games: Is it possible to reduce following using Grundy Number?

Tags: game-theory

Following is the problem from a finished programming contest.

> Two players try to create a number, DesiredTotal, by adding numbers
>   from 1 to N. The first to cross the number is the winner. The number to be
>   added cannot be repeated. For example, if one player used 4 to increase the sum from
>   20 to 24, the neither player can use 4 again in the game.

Now I understand how the above problem could be solved using dynamic programming by exploring all the possible paths and memoizing the solution, but the game being impartial still qualifies to be a Nim game.

Am I correct that, it is a Nim game? If yes, could somebody help me to reduce into a Nim game?

Below is the source but it requires signing in.

Theory: https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/algorithm-games/

Source: https://leetcode.com/contest/leetcode-weekly-contest-10/problems/can-i-win/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "A nim game." Could you define this class of games?

Comment: Here you go: https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/algorithm-games/

Comment: Why the negative vote? It is a finished contest and I am trying to grasp the theory on Nim games by practising some questions?

Comment: Your example is not formulated very well. It seems that once 4 is used, *neither* player can use it again.

Comment: Sources which aren't accessible aren't useful.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Sorry about that, but source was shared as the courtesy to the original writer. I tried to explain the question best. I have corrected the language of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your game is an impartial game, and so it is covered by the [Sprague–Grundy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem), which say that it is equivalent to a "nimber". Note that the state of the game consists of the current value of the sum as well as the current set of allowed addends. You can compute the Grundy function, which gives the equivalence to Nim, using dynamic programming.

Comment: Thanks, I guess so. I will think more along the lines you mentioned. If not able to reduce, I will ping back. Grundy number is the unique number to denote the state of the game. So do I have to find the function to map state(sum,set) to a grundy number?

English is not my mother tongue, so I apologize if I miss the clarity.

Comment: @MangatRaiModi The Grundy function gives the mapping to Nim.